# In laravel 7 app added jquery raise error

Tags: laravel

In my new laravel 7 app I added jquery with yarn command and
in package.json I have :

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
}
```

But when in my resources/js/app.js I set lines :

```
require('jquery');

require('./bootstrap');

var Turbolinks = require("turbolinks")
Turbolinks.start()

console.log('!! resources/js/app.js jQuery.fn.tooltip.Constructor.VERSION::')
console.log(jQuery.fn.tooltip.Constructor.VERSION)
```

I got an error :

```
app.js:30245 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Also I tried to use line :

```
console.log($.fn.tooltip.Constructor.VERSION)
```

But got similar error ...

I suppose I do not have to set link to jquery.js file in my resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php file ?

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `require('jquery')`, will only return a new jQuery object using its `module.exports`. It will not register `$` or `jQuery` in the global namespace. To be able to use `$('#button')` you need to register `$` in the global namespace.

In your `bootstrap.js` or before you use anything jquery in `app.js` you can register them in the global scope ( The `window` object). As you can see from the boiler plate that comes with a default laravel install, you can register jquery like so:

```
/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
} catch (e) {}
```